# Where ByteRangeStreamContent class in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I start writing project on asp.net core and I can not find class `ByteRangeStreamContent`.

1. Where is it?
2. Did it was removed from asp.net core?
3. Is there replacement of this class?

UPDATE 2016-10-06

```
dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003131
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this dependency in your project.json:

```
 "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.2"
```

Then, you can use the class:

```
System.Net.Http.ByteRangeStreamContent
```

Another option is to write `ByteRangeStreamContent` to import automatically using Visual Studio:

[image: automatic import]

My project.json is (the default when creating a new web api project):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

My dotnet version is the following:

```
C:\Users\fabriciopombo>dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

And I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Comment: This assembly doesn't contains this class.

Comment: If you write `ByteRangeStreamContent` VisualStudio will give you the option to include the dependency on project.json automatically. Are you using the last version from dotnet?

Comment: Check my edited answer to see how I added the dependency.

Comment: Can you show me your `project.json` config, because VS don't suggest me to append this package?

Comment: @Denis, did you find the class?

Comment: Unfortunately, your config is using .NET framework 4.6.1, not .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ByteRangeStreamContent you can now use the FileStreamResult or FileContentResult and set EnableRangeProcessing to true.

```
new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(bytes), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/mp3"))
{
     EnableRangeProcessing = true
};
```